# How can I create an array based on another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to python, I would like to try to create a array based on another array.

If I have a array like:

```
array = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1], [5, 3]]
```

Then if the matrix would like to be created based on array if there's a value for corresponding position, like this:
In array, the first number represents row in the matrix, and the second number represents column in the matrix, such as [1, 1] means row1 and column1 have value, then = 1; there's no [1,3] in the array means row1 and column 3 equal to 0. So I want the result to be like this:

```
      col1 col2 col3
row1 [ 1    1    0 ]
row2 [ 0    1    0 ]
row3 [ 0    1    1 ]
row4 [ 0    1    0 ]
row5 [ 1    0    1 ]

result = [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Note that the value in the array is just an example not the exact position of the matrix.

I've tried the insert the value in the empty array but the corresponding position is hard to be identified in the matrix.

Another example is:

```
array =[[4, 3], [4, 23], [5, 308], [5, 432], [8, 432], [8, 429]]
```

and the matrix would be like:

```
      col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
row1 [ 1    1    0    0    0  ]
row2 [ 0    0    1    1    0  ]
row3 [ 0    0    0    1    1  ]
```

Not sure this is clear for the problem description.

Answer (score 4):

The first array (named `array`) is called a *sparse binary matrix representation*. The second array (named `result`) is called a *dense binary matrix representation*. If you want to convert the values to ranks (while respecting duplicates) beforehand, you can use the `numpy.unique` function. So, the full procedure would be:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from numpy import unique

array = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1], [5, 3]]

r_unique, rows = unique([v[0] for v in array], return_inverse=True)
c_unique, cols = unique([v[1] for v in array], return_inverse=True)
values = [1] * len(array)
n = len(r_unique)
m = len(c_unique)

result = csr_matrix((values, (rows, cols)), shape=(n, m)).toarray()
```

This works because `r_unique` is the set of all unique numbers of one dimension in `array`, which is the size of the `result` in the corresponding dimension. `rows` then contains mapping from the `number` to its `rank` within this dimension. The same applies correspondingly to `cols` and `c_unique`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is exactly what I want. Appreciate for this:))))

Comment: Sorry, I found an error, if I use another example like if the array = [[1, 3],[1,23]] and the matrix would like to be [[1,1]], but it runs and said the "column index exceeds matrix dimensions".

Comment: @TinaChiu That's because originally, I've hardcoded the output matrix dimensions in. Now, the code should automatically scale the resulting matrix for you. Try it out.

Comment: The numbers of columns are still in error. Maybe I didn't state my problem very clearly. I've already added another example that is what I try to do. Not sure it could be done in this way?

Comment: @TinaChiu Do I understand correctly that you first need to sort the elements, get their positions, and from these positions build the resulting matrix?

Comment: Oh, the logic could be stated this way. And the corresponding value would be 1.  Is that possible to build in this way?

Comment: @TinaChiu Definitely, give me a few minutes.

Comment: @TinaChiu Check this out.

Comment: It works fine in this way. Thanks a lot, @Captain Trojan :)))

Comment: You're welcome @TinaChiu, but actually, if the answer really helped you, I'd appretiate if you could accept it c:

Answer (score 1):

you can do this pretty easily with numpy

```
rows,columns = numpy.array(list(zip(*array)))
matrix_size = (6,6)
result = numpy.zeros(matrix_size)
result[(rows,columns)] = 1
print(result)
```

if your `array` values are one based you will need to make them zero based ... just change

```
result[(rows-1,columns-1)] = 1 # now we are 0 based instead of 1 based
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution without library:**

```
data_list = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1], [5, 3]]

rows_ = (max(data_list, key = lambda x : x[0] ))[0]
cols_ = (max(data_list, key = lambda x : x[1] ))[1]

matrix =  [ [0]*cols_ for r in range(rows_) ]


for data in data_list:
    row_index = data[0] - 1
    col_index = data[1] - 1
    matrix[row_index][col_index] = 1

for matrix_row in matrix:
    print(matrix_row)
```

**Reuslt:**

[image]